# php login to dashboard showing data breach alert in chrome

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, google-chrome

i have created a login page for admin in php. i have 2 admins, each admins have separate admin panels. while logging in i have given the following code to check for username and password:

```html
   <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include 'includes/dbconnection.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$adminuser = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "select ID from tbladmin where UserName='$adminuser' && Password='$password' ");
$ret = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if ($ret > 0) {
 $_SESSION['cvmsaid'] = $ret['ID'];
 header('location:dashboard.php');} else {
 $msg = "Invalid Details.";
}
}
?>
```

for first admin i have given the following for dashboard:

```html
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/dbconnection.php');
error_reporting(0);
if (strlen($_SESSION['cvmsaid']==0)) {
  header('location:logout.php');
  }

else if (strlen($_SESSION['cvmsaid']==2)) {
  header('location:dashboard2.php');
  }

   else{ ?>
```

this is working very fine for first admin.

for the second admin i have given the following:

```html
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/dbconnection.php');
error_reporting(0);
if (strlen($_SESSION['cvmsaid']==0)) {
  header('location:logout.php');
  }

else if (strlen($_SESSION['cvmsaid']==1)) {
  header('location:dashboard.php');
  }

   else{ ?>
```

now when the second admin logs in i get the following error:

[image]

whenever i login i get this alert box, i have tried changing passwords also. can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your dashboard.php code

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 https://jsfiddle.net/z04rbLu2/ complete dashboard code

Comment: What domain are you using? Apparently chrome has a list of breached sites and does this automatically

Comment: That means that some _other_ site/app (where you had a login) has been breached. You've probably been using the same login/email on that _other_ site, so it is advised to change your login credentials. Mozilla has https://monitor.firefox.com/ where you can check if your email/password has been exposed in a breach

Comment: @kerbholz i changed my username now, the popup is gone. will it come again?

Comment: If you used that (breached) email/password combination on other sites, the popup will probably pop up there too. It is advised to change _all_ logins where that combination has been used.

Comment: if you can post it as an answer i will accept it, i know its a small mistake, but still i didnt get any answer on google for this, hope if you post an answer, it will help others

Comment: All good, don't think this deserves an answer

Comment: Don´t use old MD5 for hashing passwords, instead use php built in functions password_hash and password_verify

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirming this is a genuine message from Chrome. When you type your credentials into a website, Chrome will now warn you if your username and password have been compromised in a data breach on some site or app. It will suggest that you change them everywhere they were used.

You can control this feature in Chrome Settings under Sync and Google Services. For now, it is being gradually rolled out for everyone signed in to Chrome as a part of Google's Safe Browsing protection.

Comment: I don't find where to control the feature in Chrome Settings under Sync and Google Services